# Does MMR get reset towards average at the end of the season?

Tags: league-of-legends

As mentioned in this question [Should I avoid playing ranked for a while after the season starts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191327/should-i-avoid-playing-ranked-for-a-while-after-the-season-starts) I believe that MMR gets "averaged" at the end of each season, however I've not seen any official source for that belief.

The formula I've seen basically says that everyone's MMR gets set to `(oldMMR+1200)/2`. In other words it moves you half way towards 1200 from where you are now.

Is my belief correct? Are there any official sources to confirm what happens?

The only thing I've been able to find is this from [last year](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/competitive/ranked-play-info-and-faq-preseason) which says that they would be doing a "soft rankings reset". That may be where this comes from but I've found nothing for this year.

Comment: That looks like pure speculation based on nothing. Only thing that changes between seasons is that you get placed again, so if you play significant worse between seasons, you might get placed in a lower tier next season. That should only be a risk if you are already playing in division V of your current tier. In fact, if you are already in division V, it's not unthinkable you are already going to be placed in a lower tier next season, and winning games between season can save you from that.

Comment: That formulat looks, well weird... I think it is `(oldMMR + 1200) / 2` which will result in the same answer as your formula it's just 'easier'. Apart from that, I do remember something along the line of what you formulated in your question. I don't know any source

Comment: You are right, that's an easier way to see it so I updated the formula. @Whoeever downvoted. Why downvote the question? If the reset doesn't happen then post that as an answer, it doesn't make this a bad question though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what the exact formula is, but you are correct.  There is sort of a soft reset between seasons but I'm not completely sure how strongly it is.  When you are at lower/mid ELOs you don't notice the push too much, but it's very noticeable at high ELOs (which is completely supported by the Math).  Last season I ended up around mid to upper Diamond.  When this season started, I began in Platinum 1 after doing extremely well (7/10 I believe) in my placement matches.

TL;DR;  **Yes**, but I'm not 100% sure on the formula but it's likely something close to that.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

Your MMR of the previous season will be taken into account when you play your placement matches of the following season. If you are Gold V you will be likely placed at the same ranking if you play average for your level.

This ofcourse means if you do better than average, you will be likely placed higher than Gold V and vice versa if you play worse than average.

The 1200 ELO formula only counts for Summoners who have never played ranked games before.
(Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elo_rating_system)

Soft ranking reset indeed means you get to play your 10 placement matches again to get you placed at your level.

Comment: sources for this?

Comment: Nobody actually confirmed this, I know. As far as I know not by Riot Games themself. This is based off my own experience since I play the game for four years. The 1200 ELO formula actually IS true. Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Elo_rating_system

Comment: This article or section contains obsolete information, but exists here for historical purposes.

Comment: @Praetorae I believe your answer is actually incorrect.  I don't have time to look up the exact wording on the ELO adjustments but I do remember researching this info last year.  Last year I ended last season in mid to high diamond and then was placed in Plat 1 after doing very well in placements, which doesn't doesn't agree with your guess.